# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'submit'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'submit'" when I try to add ajaxSubmit to my form.

JQuery code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var options = {
        beforeSubmit:  showRequest,
        success:       showResponse
    };

    $('#bform').submit(function() {
        $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
        return false;
    });
});

function showRequest(formData, jqForm, options) {
    var queryString = $.param(formData);
    alert('About to submit: \n\n' + queryString);
    return true;
}

function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form)  {
    alert('status: ' + statusText + '\n\nresponseText: \n' + responseText +
            '\n\nThe output div should have already been updated with the responseText.');
}
```

The form HTML:

```
<form id="bform" action="/rest/submit_byte" method="post">
    <label for="submitted_byte">Submit a Byte:</label>
    <textarea id="submitted_byte" name="submitted_byte" style="margin: 2px; width: 385px; height: 201px;"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" id="submit_button" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: I'm afraid the problem is not on the code you show. I wonder if any other js library is conflicting with jquery.

Comment: Are you using this http://malsup.com/jquery/form/ ? My guess is you've not imported the JavaScript file for the plug-in / library you're attempting to use.

Comment: works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/m87s4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code worked for me... http://dev.orangedigital.com.au/test/stack/2013-04-17/

I also had to add the jQuery Form plugin for the ajaxSubmit method: http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

Comment: Turns out the jQuery Form plugin I was storing locally was corrupted somehow. I'm using the remotely hosted version for now.